# Using webpack and FontAwesome 5 Pro, generate a strange prefix

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using Laravel and Webpack, I add to my **app.scss** the path to nodemodules with FontAwesome5 Pro:

```
// Variables
@import 'variables_env';
@import 'variables';

// External
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/solid';
```

Inside the folder node_modules, I see that fontawesome has the fonts named with fa-regular, fa-solid, etc:
[image]

The problem is when Webpack compiles my app.scss, and generates fontawesome fonts with a "web" prefix: webfa-light, webfa-regular, etc:
[image]

This is my webpack.mix.js config:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

var settingsPath = '.';
//development, preproduction, production
settingsPath = 'resources/sass/_enviroments/'+process.env.NODE_ENV;

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
      includePaths: [settingsPath],
   })
   .extract(['vue','bootstrap-vue','vee-validate'])
   .browserSync('newregalospersonales.local');
```

When does Webpack rename the files? Can I change the "web" prefix?

Comment: Can you show your webpack config?

Comment: @Jerodev i edited the main post